# PHP Regular express to remove <h1> tags (and their content)

Tags: php, regex

Hay, i can't seem to find any regular expressions online to remove

```
<h1></h1>
```

tags (and their content).

Anyone lend a hand on this and help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Preemptive counter examples: `<h1 id="a"></h1>`, `<h1><b></b></h1>`, `<h1><!--</h1>--></h1>`, `<script>alert(x<h1>0&&x</h1>/);</script>`

Comment: @David: A classic response! Well done :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use a regex, use a tool like [PHP Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

```
// Construct dom from string
$dom = str_get_html($html);

// ...or construct dom from file/url
$dom = file_get_html($path);

// strip h1 tags (and their content)
foreach ($dom->find('h1') as $node) {
    $node->outertext = '';
}
```

Comment: Why use an external class when PHP provides the DOMDocument class

Comment: I said "a tool *like* PHP Simple HTML DOM", not "You absolutely should use PHP Simple HTML DOM". I chose to demo it, because it's a tool I'm personally familiar with, like using for it's simplicity, and am able to provide an example for.

Comment: I find DOMDocument a bit complicated.

Answer (score 5):

```
preg_replace('@<h1[^>]*?>.*?<\/h1>@si', '', $htmlsource);
```

Comment: for your one case but not, I suspect, in all instance.  use with caution.

Comment: For all its simplicity. When you know your html and you just need the h1 stripped, this will do just fine

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [PHP's DOM extension module](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php):

```
$domDocument = new DOMDocument;
$domDocument->loadHTMLFile('http://example.com');
$domNodeList = $domDocument->getElementsByTagname('h1');
$domElemsToRemove = array();
foreach ($domNodeList as $domElement) {
    $domElemsToRemove[] = $domElement;
}
foreach($domElemsToRemove as $domElement) {
    $domElement->parentNode->removeChild($domElement);
}
var_dump($domDocument->saveHTML());
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot find one, because there is none.

Regular expressions are not a good fit for this task, since the `<h1>` tags may be nested arbitrarily deep. (Edit: Tomalak pointed out that they are not allowed to, but reality is evil). Try a HTML parser instead.

Turbod's expression will work, if you can be sure that nowhere in your document can be a construct like `<h1>Foo <h1> Bar</h1></h1>`.

**Edit:**
Depending on your scenario, a css style like `h1 { display: none !important; }` might do the trick.

Comment: `<h1>` tags may be nested arbitrarily deep? Not when I last looked a the spec. ;-) The real problem is that the HTML might be horribly broken and a regex has no way of recognizing.

Comment: @Tomalak: *cough* I never looked at the spec. =) But unfortunately, I am not alone there, and the tags will be nested anyways. The spec allows comments that may contain `<h1>` tags, though.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use regexp, this works for me:

```
$str = preg_replace("/<h1>.*?<\/h1>/si", '', $str);
```

The question mark switches content between tags to be non-greedy. That is necessary for case when you have multiple h1 tags so it will always only take the content between each of them instead of removing everything between first opening [h1] and last closing [/h1]

The 'i' modifier says to ignore uppercase/lowercase difference, and 's' says to work multiline.