# preg replace h2 tags with spaces

Tags: php, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Regular express to remove <h1> tags (and their content)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911481/php-regular-express-to-remove-h1-tags-and-their-content)

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<h2>
Fund Management</h2>
<p>
The majority of property investments are now made via our Funds.</p>
```

Trying to use a regular expression to strip h2 tags but doesn't work because of the space between the opening and closing h2 tags.

```
preg_replace('/<h2>(.+?)<\/h2>/', '', $content);
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Also I would ideally like it to replace h1-h6 tags so maybe it needs [1-6] or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only problem of your regex was the lack of modifiers (the `si` thingy) but if you you want to extend it to match from `<h1>` to `<h6>` tags, you can accomplish this by using a back-reference from first tag:

```
preg_replace("/<h([1-6]{1})>.*?<\/h\\1>/si", '', $content);
```

This way you ensure your first tag to match the second.

You can learn more about the modifiers here:

[reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)